How to prove $10^{m-1}>9m+81$ is true if and only if $m\geq4$ for m positive integers.
I got this claim when solving an olympiad problem.
The only method that I could think of is using tangent line trick.
However finding the derivative of $10^{m-1}$ would be annoying personally.
Are there any other way that you could prove that?

Perhaps $(1+9)^{m-1}$ helps.

Induction does for "if", and "only if" is easy.

I also recommend induction.

For $m\ge 4$ we have $$(1+9)^{m-1} >9(m-1)+9^2{m-1\choose 2}\\  \ge 9(m-1)+81(m-1) =90(m-1) =90(m-2)+90\\ ={2(m-2)\over m}45m+90\ge 45m+90$$
In this way we got a stronger inequality for $m\ge 4.$ Moreover we do not need to verify the case $m=4,$ unlike in the induction method, although the case $m=4$ can be easily verified by hand.

You've only shown the if side.

@CalvinLin Indeed, I have skipped verification for $m=1,2,3.$
